# How do I get my printer back?

Tags: windows-xp, printing, windows-10-v1703

I've been configured to print via a Windows XP box (functioning purely as a print server) for awhile.  Things were great, progressed from Vista up through Windows 10 1607 on the client side without any issues.  Then I installed the 1703 "Creator's Update".  I can no longer print.  Windows 10 refuses to see the XP box nevermind the attached printer.  Is there any trick to get back the ability to print to Windows XP print servers on Windows 10 v1703?

Comment: I gave up on Windows shared printing.  After that update I never got XP connectivity working again and after far too many long evenings fighting with homegroup (which only ever seems to work intermittently and sometimes just completely goes belly up and has to be re-created) I acquired individual printers and direct connected them all.  Printer sharing with current versions of Windows 10 is a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Turn features ON or OFF]
[image: SMB 1.0]

Although as far as security goes this is terrible idea.  You might get it to work again this way.

Comment: To add to this, mainly for the OP and other visitors, that in light of the WannaCry ransomware you should not be enabling SMB 1.0 unless you really, really, really, really, really have to. Formatting the XP box and sticking a recent Linux version on and installing Samba is a free solution that will allow you to keep using the machine as a print server! Upgrading the print server machine should be a critical priority, IMO.

Comment: Unfortunately replacing XP on that box is not an option.  I've also still got XP only software on there that I need and a budget of $0...

Comment: (6/8/17) You clearly state **Windows XP box (functioning purely as a print server)** So this is what a massive oversight?  Linux $0  Samba $0 Most linux software $0.  All upgrades including the OS $0.  Total that up 0+0+0+0+0 =0 it meets your budgets exactly.  It will take a few hours to setup.  There maybe free software equilivant in Linux for mystery software.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem every time a Windows 10 update hits, disabling access to the XP machine which is also my print server.

I don't have a cut-and-dried certainty answer, but I've had to repair it numerous times.  Part of the problem seems to be that 'Workgroup' disappears and 'Homegroup' is substituted.

I don't want to reconfigure all of my network - especially as XP doesn't understand Homegroup - so restoring 'Workgroup' on Win10 is the first step.  This may restore some visibility of the XP machine to Win10.  (The XP-PC may also need rebooting.  In the worst case, I've had to reinstall XP on the print server to get it visible as a PC to Win10.)

If you can now see the XP-PC from Win10, try removing and adding your remote printer on the Win10 PC.   You may also need to do the same on the XP-PC.  This is usually enough with reboots, but it is incredibly frustrating and time-wasting.

This doesn't seem to be a selections issue, so much as permissions and general configuration becoming screwed up'?